# После смены ориентации экрана приложение работает не корректно

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение на android, в нём четыре кнопки, при нажатии на них, каждая отправляет свои данные через Socket. Приложение работает исправно, но после смены ориентации экрана, при нажатии на кнопку 1 отправляются данные кнопки 4.

```
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button connection;
Button disconnection;
TextView IpAddress;
TextView NewPort;

int b;

private Socket socket;

private int SERVERPORT;
private String SERVER_IP;

ClientThread client;

private Timer mTimer;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask1;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask2;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask3;
private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask4;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    connection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connection);
    disconnection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnection);
    IpAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IpAdd);
    NewPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PortAdd);

    connection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                SERVER_IP = IpAddress.getText().toString();
                SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(NewPort.getText().toString());

                client = new ClientThread();
                Thread thread = new Thread(client);
                thread.start();

                disconnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        b = 1;
                        if (mTimer != null) {
                            mTimer.cancel();
                        }
                        mTimer = new Timer();
                        mMyTimerTask1 = new MyTimerTask();

                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask1, 0, 250);
                        }
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                            mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask1, 0, 250);
                        }
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            mTimer.cancel();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    public void run() {
                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String str) {
        out.write(str);
        out.flush();
    }
}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (b == 1) mMyTimerTask1();
        if (b == 2) mMyTimerTask2();
        if (b == 3) mMyTimerTask3();
        if (b == 4) mMyTimerTask4();
    }


}

private void mMyTimerTask1() {
    client.sendMessage("F");        //1
}
```

Comment: Что значит "Ложные данные"? И уберите лишнее из вопроса. Объявления полей класса не нужны тут, идентичные слушатели кликов тоже. Локализуйте проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить onSaveInstanceState (сохранение состояния активити): 
[пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana)